# Joomla Seblod cck Same Alias Error

Tags: syntax-error, alias, joomla3.0, article

I have this error below whenever my form is submitted with an article title that is in existance.

** *Error: Another article from this category has the same alias (remember it may be a trashed item). An error has occurred.* **

Version: Seblod 3.7.2, Joomla 3.4.5

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

It's a topic related to Joomla not SEBLOD.

https://docs.joomla.org/Alias

Such as the message said you, you can not have 2 times the same alias. An alias must be unique.

A workaround with SEBLOD can be to not used the native Joomla title field in your forms. In this cas the Joomla title will be set with the current date. And to add another field for the title which no relation with an alias.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. I finally got a plugin to fix this at: https://www.seblod.com/community/forums/fields-plug-ins/unique-alias-automaticly

Thanks for you time.